# Как Entity Framework отслеживает изменение объектов?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Как Entity Framework отслеживает изменение объектов? Еще когда через методы идет вызов понятно, а как он отслеживает объект который мы получили, сделали изменение и вызвали метод сохранить? Мол по факту мы записали в свой же класс.
Например:

```
using(UserContext db = new UserContext())
{
     db.Users.Where(w=>w.Id==3).First().Name="Ivan";
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

П.С. В примере получили пользователя с Id равным 3 и поменяли ему имя. Как EF отследило изменение? И как можно сделать самому отслеживание элементов?

Comment: EF хранит ссылки на все выбранные через него объекты, хранит значения свойств в момент выборки, и по SaveChanges сравнивает их с текущими значениями свойств объекта.

Comment: @PashaPash Хотите сказать что он пробегает по всем объектам и сравнивает каждое поле на изменение? Так эта операция очень долгая и медленная, особенно на большое количество данных.

Comment: @ИльяАнтипанов В том числе и поэтому не рекомендуется долго держать открытым контекст без особой нужды. Открыл контекст, внёс изменения или считал данные - закрыл контекст.

Comment: EF создаёт обёртку (proxy) над каждым объектом. Этот прокси содержит дополнительные свойства, одно из которых - состояние сущности (EntityState).

Comment: Вы работали когда-нибудь с DataSet/DataTable? Строка в DataTable является аналогом прохи в EntityFramework. DataRow содержит текущие и предыдущие значения ячеек и дополнительные свойства, в том числе состояние. Причём всё это хозяйство видно снаружи без ухищрений. А в сущности EF его не видно просто так: нужно смотреть в отладчике или рефлексией.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А как они тогда лямбда выражения преобразуют в запрос?

Comment: А как связано преобразование лямбды с отслеживанием состояния?

Comment: Если вас интересует преобразование лямбд в запрос, то ищите информацию по [деревьям выражений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) (Expression trees). И вообще, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Видит небо, я хотел вам ответить, но увидев [Жетобжекттипе](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/fundamentals/proxies#getting-the-actual-entity-type-from-a-proxy-type), я должен отсмеяться и уйти на перезагрузку... ЗЫ: читайте документацию в оригинале.

Comment: @ИльяАнтипанов И если вам хочется сократить эту долгую и медленную операцию то можно использовать `.AsNoTracking()` в дополнение к "не держать долго контектс" и "используйте несколько DbContext".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрел доку. В общем, EF просто хранит "снимок" всех объектов и потом проверяет для всех "присоединённых" объектов соответствие этому "снимку", чтобы найти изменения.

> При использовании большинства сущностей POCO (plain old CLR object)
> определение того, каким образом изменилась сущность (и, следовательно,
> какие обновления необходимо отправить в базу данных), обрабатывается
> алгоритмом обнаружения изменений. **Обнаружение изменений
> осуществляется путем обнаружения различий между текущими значениями
> свойств сущности и значениями исходных свойств, которые хранятся в
> моментальном снимке при запросе или присоединении сущности.**

[Автоматическое обнаружение изменений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/auto-detect-changes)

[Работа с состояниями сущностей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

Answer (score 2):

EF создаёт обёртку (proxy) над каждым объектом. Этот прокси содержит дополнительные свойства, одно из которых - состояние сущности ([EntityState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entitystate?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Также там содержатся текущие и предыдущие значения сущности.

В псевдокоде эту выглядит так:

```
// entity
// Класс, который мы создали
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// proxy
// Класс, который генерируется
public class UserProxy
{
    public User Current { get; set; }
    public User Previous { get; set; }
    public EntityState State { get; set; }
    // другие свойства
    // ...
}
```

Когда мы добавляем, удаляем или изменяем сущности, то эти свойства соответственно меняются.

При вызове метода `SaveChanges` происходит примерно следующее:

```
foreach (UserProxy user in context.Users)
{
    if (user.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        // выполняется sql-запрос INSERT
    }
    else if (user.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        // выполняется sql-запрос DELETE
    }
    else if (user.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        // выполняется sql-запрос UPDATE
    }
}
```

Ещё раз повторю, что это псевдокод. На самом деле всё несколько сложнее.

Comment: прокси - это больше для отслеживания связей. если объект - poco, и в нем нет вирутальных свойств (как в вашем примере, и как в примере топикастера), то прокси не создается. Т.е. да, снимок свойств User будет лежать где-то в контексте, но сам объект User будет в вызывающем коде просто инстансом класса User, а не оберткой поверх него.

Comment: об этом кстати прямо сказано в документации "в оригинале" по вашей ссылке :) Note that the EF will not create proxies for types where there is nothing for the proxy to do. This means that you can also avoid proxies by having types that are sealed and/*or have no virtual properties*.

Comment: @PashaPash - ok, понял.